# Ambiguous function overload resolution with gcc. Why?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, gcc-warning

Let's say i have the following code

```
enum MyEnum {Value1 = -1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5};

class OtherClass // Added after solving the problem
{
public:
    OtherClass(int p1 = 0, int p2 = 0, int p3 = 1, int p4 = 0, double p5 = 0);
    OtherClass(const Size<int> p1, const int p2 = 1, const int p3 = 0, const double p4 = 0);
}

class MyBase
{
protected:
    virtual boost::optional<MyEnum> myBadFunc(const OtherClass& o) = 0;
}

class MyClass : MyBase
{
private:
    virtual boost::optional<MyEnum> myBadFunc(const OtherClass& o);
    MyEnum myBadFunc(const unsigned int ui) const;

    void callingFunc(unsigned int value);
}
```

Now i'm trying to call `myBadFunc()` from inside `callingFunc()` like this:

```
void MyClass::callingFunc(unsigned int value)
{
    MyEnum retVar;

    retVar = myBadFunc(value); // Line which causes Warning!
}
```

On the line with the comment i'm getting the warning:

> Warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: [enabled by default]
>      retVar = myBadFunc(value);

Which is weird because i don't see why overload resolution shoudn't decide to use the second(not inherited) version of `myBadFunc()`.

I know this code looks somewhat weird. That's because it's a simplified version of a class used in our company's software and refactoring it would be lots of work.

I'm using gcc v4.8.5 with the flags `-Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -fopenmp` and boost library v1.58(in case it has something to do with `boost::optional`).

My concrete question would be:

**What's the reason for this warning in this concrete case and how can i fix it?**

Comment: This doesn't reproduce as is. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Which version of gcc do you use and with what flags?

Comment: I'm using gcc v4.8.5 with the flags `-Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -fopenmp` and boost v1.58.

Comment: Does OtherClass have a non-explicit constructor that can invoked with an `unsigned int` parameter?

Comment: @lubgr - No. It has a lot of constructors but none with unsigned int and none with less than 2 parameters.

Comment: I can't reproduce the warnings with the flags you mentioned (gcc version 8 and clang).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i found the problem.
It was a problem with the constructors of `OtherClass`. There was no constructor only taking an unsigned int as lubgr asked about in his comment. But there were two constructors which took an int followed by multiple other parameters.

After taking another look on this class i realized the other parameeters are optional which means they could implicitely have been used as converting constructor.

Making them `explicit` fixed the warning.

```
class OtherClass
{
public:
    explicit OtherClass(int p1 = 0, int p2 = 0, int p3 = 1, int p4 = 0, double p5 = 0);
    explicit OtherClass(const Size<int> p1, const int p2 = 1, const int p3 = 0, const double p4 = 0);
}
```

Thanks to lubgr